# Download xml file from https using php

Tags: php, xml

I can download xml file when I click on https://www.omniva.ee/locations.xml.

Is it possible to get the contents of this file using PHP and save these to a MySQL database?

I tried this example but without any result (no arrors found but php.ini file on server has value 0):

PHP Version 5.6.19
Directive   Local value Master value
allow_url_fopen 0   0
allow_url_include   no value    no value

```
$xml = file_get_contents("https://www.omniva.ee/locations.xml");
```

Comment: What it means “without any result”? The file is not loaded?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php - what is the value of your `allow_url_fopen` setting? can you download files from non-https sites? do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: Improved question. Still not clear what 'without any result' means. Is `$xml` empty? Is there an error occurring?

Comment: I can't download file from http as well. allow_url_fopen = 0. No errors show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `allow_url_fopen` is disabled you have no possibility to get the file content of the external file with `file_get_contents()`. Instead of using `file_get_contents()` you can use `curl` to get the content of the file:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.omniva.ee/locations.xml');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    //check if the curl_exec was successful.
    if (curl_errno($curl) === 0) {
        //success - file could be downloaded.
        //write the content of $data in database here...
    } else {
        //error - file could not be downloaded.
    }

    //close the curl session.
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got result 'error - file could not be downloaded.'. It looks i haven't any chance to download the file. Am I right? :-(

Comment: output of `var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));` and `var_dump(curl_errno($curl));`?

Comment: var_dump(function_exists('curl_version')) -> bool(true);   var_dump(curl_errno($curl)) -> bool(false)